# Define function's variable to another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have many buttons and its values is contain usernames (jason,chan,brad etc..) and user click the button and this button appended to  specific div. Example:

```
<input type="button" onClick="nano();" id="name1" class="names"  name="jason" value="jason" />
```

and it is converted to

```
<div id="name_selected"><input type="button" id="name1" class="added_name"  name="jason" value="jason" /></div>
```

when user clicks button then nano function is running

```
function nano(){
$("#name1").click(function(){
$(this).appendTo("div#name_selected").removeClass("names");
$(this).addClass("added_name");
var name_value=$(this).attr("value");

});
}
```

and real question is i want to get value of selected button and save to database using ajax and how do i define name_value variable to function ajaxSubmit()?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: name_value is not defined
```

error occur

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"z.php",
                cache:false,
                data:name_value,
                success:function(data) {
                    window.location.href="show.php";
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: why you put and event listener inside a function already fired when the button is clicked !!

Comment: it is not form submit buttons.

Comment: real button is <input id="sub_but" onClick="ajaxSubmit();" type="submit" value="Add names" class="but_final">

Comment: you have onclick attribut in you input fires a function called nano() and inside this function you listen on click `#name1` which is the same input , why you do like this !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all declare a function that is going to be called on button click:

```
/**
*   Function that performs various operations on button click
*   @param btn {jQuery object}: The button that triggered the click event
*/
function nano(btn) {   
   // Do your stuff here...       
   btn.appendTo("div#name_selected")
      .removeClass("names")
      .addClass("added_name");

   // Get the value attribute
   var name_value = btn.attr("value");

   // Make ajax call
   if (name_value) {
      ajaxSubmit(name_value);
   }       
}
```

Declare the function that is going to perform the ajax call:

```
function ajaxSubmit(val) {
    // Check if 'val' is not undefined
    if (val) {
       $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"z.php",
          cache:false,
          data: { val: val },
          success:function(data) {
             window.location.href="show.php";
          },
          error:function() {
             // error handling here...
          }
       });
    }
}
```

Add an event listener on the desired elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-class', function() {
   // Call nano passing the clicked button as parameter
   // this --> the javascript object that triggered the click event
   // $(this) --> the jQuery object of 'this' 
   nano($(this));
});
```

---

**IMPORTANT**:

Remove `onClick` attributes from all your buttons! (**Don't use it**, instead use the `on()` function to add event listeners)

Answer (score 0):

Declare name_value outside function nano which will act as global variable and accessed by other javascript/jquery function. Like this

```
var name_value;

function nano(){
...
name_value=$(this).attr("value");
...
}
```

You can directly use `name_value` directly in your ajax. It will solve your problem/error.

Comment: how do i declare name_value to ajaxSubmit function?

Comment: Do you need more help ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `var name_value;` outside and above all functions, then change value of `name_value` by calling `name_value = $(this).attr("value");`

Final code:

```
var name_value;

function nano(){
$("#name1").click(function(){
$(this).appendTo("div#name_selected").removeClass("names");
$(this).addClass("added_name");
name_value=$(this).attr("value");

});
}

function ajaxSubmit(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"z.php",
                cache:false,
                data:name_value,
                success:function(data) {
                    window.location.href="show.php";
                }
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your `onclick` function is not needed as you are already binding the click even inside of your `nano` function. Inside your `ajaxSubmit` function, get the value of #name1 like so.

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "z.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            name_value: $('#name1').val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = "show.php";
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to pass whatever data you want to send when calling the function.

```
function nano(){
    $("#name1").click(function(){
       $(this).appendTo("div#name_selected").removeClass("names");
       $(this).addClass("added_name");
       var name_value=$(this).attr("value");
       ajaxSubmit(name_value);
    });
}

function ajaxSubmit(userVal){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"z.php",
                cache:false,
                data:{name_value:userVal},
                success:function(data) {
                    window.location.href="show.php";
                }
            });
```

}